# Traveling from US to Jamaica, back to US on B1 visa

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, jamaica

My parents are in the US on B1/B2 visitor visa and we plan to take a short vacation with them to Jamaica. I read up on the Jamaica website, it mentioned that Indian citizens dont need a visa to travel to Jamaica. My question is, upon return to the US, will it be considered as a new entry, anyone with such an experience?

I read up the CBP website [Can I go to other countries while I'm in the U.S. on a B1 or B2 Visa?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/751/~/traveling-to-other-countries-while-in-the-u.s.-on-a-b1-or-b2-visa) and it mentions that its indeed considered as a new entry. My parents are flying back to India a month after we return from Jamaica, so want to make sure there is no issue for them to come back to US and then fly back to India.

I would appreciate any thoughts or experiences on this matter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long will you parents have been in the US when they leave for Jamaica? How long are they planning on staying in the US after they come back?

Comment: And what did they tell CBP when they arrived in the US? Did they disclose the trip to Jamaica and return to the US? If they were asked, I'd presume whatever they said will pop up on the screen when they present themselves at US Immigration for the second time.

Comment: Putting on hold until OP returns to clarify.